how to find and optimize the decenter and tilt of measurement data?

I attempted to optimize the decenter and tilt of measurement data using least squares as follows:

code #1 ~ #4 : generate measurement data

Define the xy-polynomial equation.
Define a function using least squares to optimize the decenter and tilt.
Generate a basic example file to create measurement data.
Generate measurement data including decenter and tilt based on arbitrary values (a, b, c, dx, dy).

code #5 ~ #7 : optimize decenter and tilt

Use the least squares function to calculate a, b, c, dx, dy, and compute alignment data.
Calculate design value and pv_error
plot 3D

When I ran the code with the arbitrarily set(a, b, c, dx, dy) for testing, I noticed significant differences between the arbitrarily set values and the calculated results obtained from executing the code.
how can I optimize the measurement data?
Your assistance is urgently needed.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

# 1. define: equation of XYpolynomial 
vars = [2.9751454685e+02, -2.8125566361e-03, 1.5162246788e-04, -2.5070930367e-03]
def func_xypoly(XY, YR=0.0, C04=0.0,C05=0.0,C06=0.0):
    X, Y = XY
    r   = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    Zsph  = ((1/YR) * r**2) / (1 + (1-((1/YR)*r)**2)**0.5) if YR!=0.0 else 0.0
    Zsumc = C04*X**2*Y**0 + C05*X**1*Y**1 + C06*X**0*Y**2 
    Zpolynomial = Zsph + Zsumc
    return Zpolynomial

# 2. define: leastsquares for optimize
def func_lsquares(params, df_cmm):
    a_rad, b_rad, c_rad, dx, dy = params
    
    X, Y, Z = df_cmm['mea_X'], df_cmm['mea_Y'], df_cmm['mea_Z']
    cosA, sinA = np.cos(c_rad), np.sin(c_rad)
    cosB, sinB = np.cos(b_rad), np.sin(b_rad)
    cosG, sinG = np.cos(a_rad), np.sin(a_rad)

    X_new =  X*cosA*cosB + Y*(cosA*sinB*sinG - sinA*cosG) + Z*(cosA*sinB*cosG + sinA*sinG) + dx
    Y_new =  X*sinA*cosB + Y*(sinA*sinB*sinG + cosA*cosG) + Z*(sinA*sinB*cosG - cosA*sinG) + dy
    Z_new = -X*sinB      + Y*cosB*sinG                    + Z*cosB*cosG          

    XYmesh   = (X_new.to_numpy(), Y_new.to_numpy())
    design_Z = func_xypoly(XYmesh, *vars)
    diff_Zd  = Z_new.to_numpy() - design_Z
    pv_error = np.max(diff_Zd) - np.min(diff_Zd) 
    return pv_error

# 3. generate example data
Xrange, Yrange = np.arange(-100, 101, 20), np.arange(-50, 51, 25)
XYmesh = np.meshgrid(Xrange, Yrange)
Zmesh = func_xypoly(XYmesh,  *vars)

list_xyz = [XYmesh[0].ravel(), XYmesh[1].ravel(), Zmesh.ravel()]
df_cmm = pd.DataFrame({'exam_X': list_xyz[0], 'exam_Y': list_xyz[1],'exam_Z': list_xyz[2]})

# 4. modified emample data
X, Y, Z = df_cmm['exam_X'], df_cmm['exam_Y'], df_cmm['exam_Z']

# set arbitrary variables
a_rad, b_rad, c_rad, dx, dy = -0.0009, 0.0005, 0.055, 0.110, -0.052
print(f'set: {a_rad, b_rad, c_rad, dx, dy}')

cosA, sinA = np.cos(c_rad), np.sin(c_rad)
cosB, sinB = np.cos(b_rad), np.sin(b_rad)
cosG, sinG = np.cos(a_rad), np.sin(a_rad)

# generating measurement data based on arbitraty variables
df_cmm['mea_X'] =  X*cosA*cosB + Y*(cosA*sinB*sinG - sinA*cosG) + Z*(cosA*sinB*cosG + sinA*sinG) + dx
df_cmm['mea_Y'] =  X*sinA*cosB + Y*(sinA*sinB*sinG + cosA*cosG) + Z*(sinA*sinB*cosG - cosA*sinG) + dy
df_cmm['mea_Z'] = -X*sinB      + Y*cosB*sinG                    + Z*cosB*cosG 

# 5. optimize decenter and tilt => calculate alignment data
initial_abcxy = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
find_abcxy    = least_squares(func_lsquares, initial_abcxy, args=(df_cmm,))
a_rad, b_rad, c_rad, dx, dy = find_abcxy.x
print(f'cal: {a_rad, b_rad, c_rad, dx, dy}')

X, Y, Z = df_cmm['mea_X'], df_cmm['mea_Y'], df_cmm['mea_Z']
cosA, sinA = np.cos(c_rad), np.sin(c_rad)
cosB, sinB = np.cos(b_rad), np.sin(b_rad)
cosG, sinG = np.cos(a_rad), np.sin(a_rad)

df_cmm['align_X'] =  X*cosA*cosB + Y*(cosA*sinB*sinG - sinA*cosG) + Z*(cosA*sinB*cosG + sinA*sinG) + dx
df_cmm['align_Y'] =  X*sinA*cosB + Y*(sinA*sinB*sinG + cosA*cosG) + Z*(sinA*sinB*cosG - cosA*sinG) + dy
df_cmm['align_Z'] = -X*sinB      + Y*cosB*sinG                    + Z*cosB*cosG 

# 6. calculate design value and Zd
XYmesh = (df_cmm['align_X'].to_numpy(), df_cmm['align_Y'])
df_cmm['design_Z'] = func_xypoly(XYmesh, *vars)
df_cmm["diff_Zd"]  = (df_cmm['align_Z'] - df_cmm['design_Z'])
pv_error = abs(df_cmm['diff_Zd'].max() - df_cmm['diff_Zd'].min())*1000  # unit: um
print(f'pv_error: {pv_error}')        

# 7. plot 3d   
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(df_cmm['exam_X'],  df_cmm['exam_Y'],  df_cmm['exam_Z'],  c='r', label='example')
ax.scatter(df_cmm['mea_X'],   df_cmm['mea_Y'],   df_cmm['mea_Z'],   c='b', label='mea')
ax.scatter(df_cmm['align_X'], df_cmm['align_Y'], df_cmm['align_Z'], c='g', label='align')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.legend()
plt.show()


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
